# Servlets response based on content types

Tags: http, servlets, http-headers, http-post, content-type

When debugging my server i came across this:

when http post header is

```
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',}
```

the servlet post breakpoint **is activated**.

when http post header is

```
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json',}
```

the servlet post breakpoint is **not activated** and the request "goes nowhere".

Why is this happening? is there a default filter or something like that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I think the best resource for understanding what is going on is the servlet specifications.

See p. 44 from Servlet API specifications:

http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html

> The following are the conditions that must
>   be met before post form data will be
>   populated to the parameter set:
>
> 1. The request is an HTTP or HTTPS request.
> 2. The HTTP method is POST.
> 3. The content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 4. The servlet has made an initial call of any of the
>      getParameter family of methods on the request object.
>
> If the conditions are not met and the post fo
>   rm data is not included in the parameter
>   set, the post data must still be available
>   to the servlet via the request object’s input
>   stream. If the conditions are met, post fo
>   rm data will no longer be available for
>   reading directly from the request object’s input stream